# how to get uninstalled application name in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, uninstallation

Is it possible to get application name in my app when other applications uninstall by the user in iphone?

Thanks
vani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not with the official SDK. You might be able to do it on a phone with a jailbreak.